# Is it possible to combine multiple subplots in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

I have created three subplots. Each of them has 1 row and 3 columns. Is it possible to combine these three subplots and plot into one subplot of 1 row and 9 columns? the horizontal spacing between the set of three subplots will be slightly higher than the spacing between the plots inside a subplot.

Is this something that is doable?